# How can a rollback be done in Lotus Notes Domino

Tags: lotus-domino, rollback

OK, I am not the programmer myself. I have to work with a service called [Newsroom Information System](http://www.evoxe.tv/NIS). The part I am involved with is still running on Lotus Notes/Domino and I now have to advice any improvements to the interaction between the system and the user.

No rollback, not a single possibility to recover any modified data is one of the obstacles that really sucks.

Anyone who can tell me how he/she has dealt with this matter in the past?

Comment: What do you need to rollback? Are you talking about doing a restore from a backup?

Comment: Are you asking about the lack of an 'Undo' function in the Lotus Notes client user interface? Or are you asking about the ability to roll back transactions at the database level?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! 

It's not about restoring a backup. Just undo the latest modification would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the design (program) Notes can copy the whole design in a template. After changes have been made (in design) if you need to rol back you simply replace the design of the DB by the one of previously saved template.

For the data you may use versionning that is natively supported. But I don't recommand this approach. A backup of the DB could be simply archived. A roll back consist of replacing the DB by the previous copy (backup as @Thomas Adrian suggested)

Answer (score 0):

In the source document under queryModeChange event is create a back-end document (destination doc) and copy all items to that document. On querySave event, save the destination doc, grab the unique ID (UNID) of that document, and put it in the field of the source document.  I personally would use a action to edit the source document and not have it editable in other ways.  Easier to control the queryModeChange event.

If need to roll back the source document, you can have a button that gets the destination document based on the UNID and replaces all items with corresponding items in the destination document.

Issue I can see - the increasing number of documents.  This can be reduced by removing the destination document once the source document has been rolled back, and have an agent that would delete the destination doc after x number of days, assuming that after a bit of time roll back would not be allowed.